# Lync 2013 Client SDK - unable to turn off only my video

Tags: sdk, skype-for-business, lync, lync-2013

Is there a way to turn off outgoing (my) video in a Skype for Business conversation through the Lync 2013 SDK without resorting to keystroke simulation.

Using the SDKs VideoChannel BeginStop turns of both incoming and outgoing video in the S4B client as indicating in SDK demo comments.

I only want to turn of the outgoing video if it is possible through the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the beginStop on the participant and not the conversation ?
In Pseudo code i would try something like this:

```
var av = Conv.SelfParticipant.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo] as AVModality;
av.VideoChannel.BeginStop();
```